# Ideal way to return a scalar from function (RETURN vs. SELECT)?

Tags: postgresql, functions

There's a [blog for SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output) that says returning a scalar using `SELECT` is wasteful:

> SELECT should be used for returning resultsets, not scalars.  This procedure uses a SELECT statement to return a single value to the client.  This is inefficient because most applications will have to prepare additional objects (typically referred to as "recordsets") and other support in order to consume the result.  While it is certainly valid syntax to use SELECT to return scalar values, this does not need to be common in production code.  This is the kind of thing that can make it slightly harder for high-end applications to scale.

Does this apply to PostgreSQL as well? Should functions always use `RETURN` for outputting scalars, or is it ok to use `SELECT` whenever it's more convenient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to use `RETURN` rather than `RETURN QUERY SELECT` in pl/pgsql.

But there's no need to jump through hoops. The cost of returning results with `SELECT` is negligible compared to other costs in pl/pgsql procedures.

Everything is a result-set in PostgreSQL anyway, even a single scalar, so you're not saving much with `RETURN`.

Answer (score 1):

None of this *seems* applicable to PostgreSQL.

In PostgresSQL, you can write your functions in SQL, or in pretty much any procedural language with bindings, including plpgsql, perl, python, and javascript/v8. When you say "return with `SELECT`," I read that to mean, as a SQL function -- the only kind that can implicitly return with `SELECT`. Using SQL for your scalar functions is great, and with `SELECT` it may be even faster because it *may* be [inlined entirely](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_of_SQL_functions).

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS bigint
AS $$
  SELECT count(*) FROM bar;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

That said, the above *won't* be because it contains an aggregate. =(

If you're using pl/pgsql, see [Craig's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188619/2639).